# Check if the user is logged into google talk

Tags: android, google-talk

for my app I need to know whether the user is currently logged into google talk (which ships with most androids).
AccountManager does not seem to help..

Someone know/has an idea how to accomplish this?

Thank you for answering

Answer (score 0):

You'd Something like this should work:

```
boolean isGoogleTalkRunning(){
    ActivityManager actManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningServices = am.getRunningServices(some arbitrarily large number);
    //Search through list looking for GTalk service.
}
```

Note that you'll need to add the GET_TASKS permission in your Manifest. I'm not sure about the actual name of the gtalk service though. I was having trouble finding that.